# Python CDLL cannot load library 2 times

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

Sorry my English is very bad.
So.
I write simple Dynamic Link Library in Dev c++.
Its working nice.Today I import this is library in my python project.
Dynamic Link Library File Path:`lib/my_dll.dll` #Dialog box
config.py

```
DLL_PATH = "lib/my_dll.dll"
```

main.py(config.py)imported

```
def my_func():
   dll = CDLL(DLL_PATH)
   return dll.func1()
```

So i open python interpreter and write this.

```
from main import *
a = my_func()    #Its work nice so a == "c:\\Windows\\a.txt"
```

but i reuse this function python generate next error

```
OSErrror:[WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Supply the full path to the DLL. Also, a function that returns a null-terminated string seems dubious at best. I also don't see how that code could return a string. You didn't specify the restype anywhere. You should only load the DLL once. Why do you want to load it over and over again?

Comment: Thank you for answer.This is DLL call Windows Api File Select Dialog Box.In the function not problem.Works well.My basic project directory c:\Project. C:\Project directory  have main.py,config.py and lib directory... lib directory have my_dll.dll .So i call my_dll.dll its return me c_char_p( Selected Path). a = my_func() return me path.But i call this function again Example a= my_func() generate error

Comment: You need to set `dll.func1.restype = c_char_p`. Don't try to convert the integer result as `c_char_p(result)`. That truncates a 64-bit pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you state that your DLL function call an API function that shows a file selection dialog. File selection dialogs, unless you tell them not to, can change the working directory. Since you failed to specify a full path to the DLL, the DLL search is performed each time. The first time it succeeds because your working directory happens to be what is needed for the DLL to be found. Subsequent times the DLL search fails because your working directory has changed.

Some advice:

1. Always use either just a file name, or a full absolute path when loading a DLL. In your case I suspect that you need to use the latter.
2. You load the DLL each time your function is called. Loading it once only will suffice. Don't waste time by loading it again and again.
3. It might be easier to show the file dialog directly from Python and avoid having to create a DLL for just that purpose.
4. Your ctypes function import doesn't specify the `restype` and so I don't see how you can obtain text from that function. What's more, I don't see how you can avoid leaking memory each time you call the function. Unless the text lives in a static array.

Comment: Thank you Mr Hefferman.This works!I copy my dll file in my current directory where have main.py and config.py. And change CDLL method cdll.my_dll.my_func  its works.